# Function parameter used in jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event handler that appends a new row to a table.

```
$("#pre_script_12").change(function() {
    $("#selected_pre_scripts")
        .append("<tr><td><a href='javascript:moveScriptUp("
            + this.id
            + ")'>Move</a></td></tr>");
```

`moveScriptUp()` looks like this:

```
function moveScriptDown(id) {
    current = $("tr." + id).eq(1);
    $(current).prev().before($(current).next());
    $(current).prev().before($(current).next());
}
```

However, I am getting an error when when appending `id` to `tr.`.

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: tr.[object HTMLInputElement]
```

How can I supply the `id` as a parameter to the above JavaScript function without getting this error when attempting to use it in a jQuery selector?

Comment: or `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: change `this` to `$(this).id`

Comment: Also why is there a period '.' after tr?

Comment: @Keerthi: Because of `"tr." + id`.  He's using the `id` parameter as a class name.

Comment: Why are you appending a row every time the `#pre_script_12` element is changed?  Why not just use a (delegated) event handler?

Comment: Can you post the HTML or make a fiddle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to *quote* strings in your function call.

Right now, your `<a>` tag looks like this:

```
<a href='javascript:moveScriptUp(pre_script_12)'>Move</a>
```

In (most) browsers, all elements IDs become a global variable, so `pre_script_12` refers to the element.  You need to add quotes, so you're passing a string:

```
$("#selected_pre_scripts")
    .append("<tr><td><a href='javascript:moveScriptUp(\""
        + this.id
        + "\")'>Move</a></td></tr>");
```

P.S. I **highly** reccomend, ***not*** using inline JavaScript.  Why not bind a (delegated) event handler to call the `moveScriptUp()` function?

Comment: I agree, but it isn't my choice. Thanks for the help.